# I stuck on read sub-arrays

Tags: php, arrays, sub-array

I have an array with different first indexes.
Now, I want to read all `client_created` strings without using `$array[688]["client_created"], $array[690]["client_created"]` ...

How can I read all these `client_created` strings without using these numbers like `688, 690, 695, 700` etc.?

This is how it looks like:

```
Array
(
    [688] => Array
        (

            [client_created] => 1393324278
        )

    [690] => Array
        (
            [client_created] => 1393440457
        )
)
```

That was only 2 examples, in practice, I have over 500 items.

Comment: You say how you don't want to access the values - but not how you want to

Comment: not possible. you cannot directly access a child array without passing "through" its parent. No matter how you end up writing your code, you **MUST** have `$array[690]` somewhere in your code to get at the sub-data .

Comment: well, thank you but kainaw answered it allready. it works perfectly! :)

Answer (score 3):

Foreach will parse over the entire array.

```
foreach($myarray as $index=>$subarray)
    echo $subarray['client_created']."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably best for you would be to catch all those strings through `foreach`:

```
$values=array();
foreach($yourArray as $index => $clientCreatedArray)
{
    $values[] = $clientcreatedArray["client_created"];
}
```

Let me know if this works for you.